# Factor out constant while integrating $\int (1-x)\sqrt{x}\:dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> integrate $\int (1-x)\sqrt{x}\:dx$

Wolfram says you can factor out $\sqrt{x}\int(1-x)\:dx$ why can it be done?

Comment: It can't be done, assuming you integrate w.r.t. $x$. What did you enter into the query box _exactly_ to get this?

Comment: The integrand is not a differential form.

Comment: Yes my mistake I wrote $\sqrt{X}$ rather than $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @gbox I've edited your question, tell me please if it is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. If what you mean is evaluating
$$
\int (1-x)\sqrt{x}\:dx
$$ then I suggest to rewrite it as
$$
\int (\sqrt{x}-x\sqrt{x})\:dx=\int x^{1/2}\:dx-\int x^{3/2}\:\:dx
$$ and make use of
$$
\int x^n\:dx=\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1},\quad n \neq-1.
$$

**Remark.** You can't factor out from an integral a function of $x$ when integrating with respect to $x$.